# rbenv install 1.9.3-p429 BUILD FAILED

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I am trying to install ruby 1.9.3-p429 but I keep getting a compiling error. I've sought help from a few people around the shop and no one is able to figure it out. I was able to install ruby 2.0.0 without any errors.

The following is the text I have copied from the terminal after entering the command `rbenv install ruby-1.9.3-p429`

Here is the error msg I am getting in it's entirety:

```
Installing ruby-1.9.3-p429...

BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/64/sclwxt551_5b50b9m0s1j6z00000gn/T/ruby-build.20130521144442.70391
Results logged to /var/folders/64/sclwxt551_5b50b9m0s1j6z00000gn/T/ruby-build.20130521144442.70391.log

Last 10 log lines:
x ruby-1.9.3-p429/golf_prelude.c
/var/folders/64/sclwxt551_5b50b9m0s1j6z00000gn/T/ruby-build.20130521144442.70391/ruby-1.9.3-p429 /var/folders/64/sclwxt551_5b50b9m0s1j6z00000gn/T/ruby-build.20130521144442.70391 ~/Desktop
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/var/folders/64/sclwxt551_5b50b9m0s1j6z00000gn/T/ruby-build.20130521144442.70391/ruby-1.9.3-p429':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

This is copied directly from `config.log`

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

$ ./configure --prefix=/Users/thomasberry/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p429

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = Thomass-MacBook-Pro.local
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 12.3.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 12.3.0: Sun Jan  6 22:37:10 PST 2013; root:xnu-2050.22.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 12.3.0: Sun Jan  6 22:37:10 PST 2013; root:xnu-2050.22.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 4 processors.
2 processors are physically available.
4 processors are logically available.
Processor type: i486 (Intel 80486)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3
Primary memory available: 4.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 134 tasks, 682 threads, 4 processors
Load average: 1.40, Mach factor: 2.80
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /Users/thomasberry/.rbenv/libexec
PATH: /Users/thomasberry/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
PATH: /Users/thomasberry/.rbenv/bin
PATH: /Users/thomasberry/.rbenv/shims
PATH: /Users/thomasberry/.rbenv/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2798: checking build system type
configure:2812: result: x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
configure:2880: checking host system type
configure:2893: result: x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
configure:2913: checking target system type
configure:2926: result: x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
configure:3407: checking for C compiler version
configure:3416: /usr/bin/gcc --version >&5
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3427: $? = 0
configure:3416: /usr/bin/gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~182/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~182/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
configure:3427: $? = 0
configure:3416: /usr/bin/gcc -V >&5
llvm-gcc-4.2: argument to `-V' is missing
configure:3427: $? = 1
configure:3416: /usr/bin/gcc -qversion >&5
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: no input files
configure:3427: $? = 1
configure:3447: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3469: /usr/bin/gcc  -O3 -Wno-error=shorten-64-to-32 -march=native -O3 -I'/Users/thomasberry/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p429/include'  -L'/Users/thomasberry/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p429/lib'  conftest.c  >&5
conftest.c:1: error: bad value (native) for -march= switch
conftest.c:1: error: bad value (native) for -mtune= switch
configure:3473: $? = 1
configure:3511: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define CANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3516: error: in `/var/folders/64/sclwxt551_5b50b9m0s1j6z00000gn/T/ruby-build.20130522093258.3452/ruby-1.9.3-p429':
configure:3518: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=/usr/bin/gcc
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=' -O3 -Wno-error=shorten-64-to-32 -march=native -O3'
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value='-I'\''/Users/thomasberry/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p429/include'\'' '
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value='-L'\''/Users/thomasberry/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p429/lib'\'' '
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
ac_cv_prog_CC=/usr/bin/gcc
ac_cv_target=x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ALLOCA=''
AR=''
ARCHFILE=''
ARCH_FLAG=''
AS=''
ASFLAGS=''
BASERUBY='ruby'
BUILTIN_ENCOBJS=''
BUILTIN_TRANSOBJS=''
BUILTIN_TRANSSRCS=''
CAPITARGET=''
CC='/usr/bin/gcc'
CCDLFLAGS=''
CFLAGS=' -O3 -Wno-error=shorten-64-to-32 -march=native -O3'
CHDIR=''
COMMON_HEADERS=''
COMMON_LIBS=''
COMMON_MACROS=''
COUTFLAG=''
CP=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS='-I'\''/Users/thomasberry/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p429/include'\'' '
CPPOUTFILE=''
CXX=''
CXXFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
DLDFLAGS=''
DLDLIBS=''
DLEXT2=''
DLEXT=''
DLLWRAP=''
DOT=''
DOXYGEN=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ENABLE_SHARED=''
EXECUTABLE_EXTS=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPORT_PREFIX=''
EXTDLDFLAGS=''
EXTOUT=''
EXTSTATIC=''
GCC=''
GNU_LD=''
GREP=''
INSTALLDOC=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
LDFLAGS='-L'\''/Users/thomasberry/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p429/lib'\'' '
LDSHARED=''
LDSHAREDXX=''
LIBEXT=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBPATHENV=''
LIBPATHFLAG=''
LIBRUBY=''
LIBRUBYARG=''
LIBRUBYARG_SHARED=''
LIBRUBYARG_STATIC=''
LIBRUBY_A=''
LIBRUBY_ALIASES=''
LIBRUBY_DLDFLAGS=''
LIBRUBY_LDSHARED=''
LIBRUBY_RELATIVE=''
LIBRUBY_SO=''
LIBS=''
LINK_SO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINLIBS=''
MAJOR='1'
MAKEDIRS=''
MAKEFILES=''
MANTYPE=''
MINIOBJS=''
MINIRUBY=''
MINOR='9'
MKDIR_P=''
NM=''
NROFF=''
NULLCMD=''
OBJCOPY=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OUTFLAG=''
PACKAGE=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKG_CONFIG=''
PLATFORM_DIR=''
PREP=''
RANLIB=''
RDOCTARGET=''
RI_BASE_NAME=''
RM=''
RMALL=''
RMDIR=''
RMDIRS=''
RPATHFLAG=''
RUBYW_BASE_NAME='rubyw'
RUBYW_INSTALL_NAME=''
RUBY_BASE_NAME='ruby'
RUBY_INSTALL_NAME=''
RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION='1.9.3'
RUBY_RELEASE_DATE='2013-05-15'
RUBY_SO_NAME=''
RUNRUBY=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SOLIBS=''
STATIC=''
STRIP=''
SYMBOL_PREFIX=''
TEENY='1'
TEST_RUNNABLE=''
THREAD_MODEL=''
TRY_LINK=''
UNIVERSAL_ARCHNAMES=''
UNIVERSAL_INTS=''
USE_RUBYGEMS=''
WERRORFLAG=''
WINDRES=''
XCFLAGS=''
XLDFLAGS=''
XRUBY=''
XRUBY_LIBDIR=''
XRUBY_RUBYHDRDIR=''
XRUBY_RUBYLIBDIR=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_OBJCOPY=''
ac_ct_OBJDUMP=''
arch=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='darwin12.3.0'
build_vendor='apple'
cflags=''
configure_args=''
cppflags=''
cxxflags=' ${optflags} ${debugflags} ${warnflags}'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
debugflags=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec=''
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='darwin12.3.0'
host_vendor='apple'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
optflags=''
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/Users/thomasberry/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p429'
program_transform_name='s&^&&'
psdir='${docdir}'
ridir=''
ruby_pc=''
ruby_version=''
rubyhdrdir=''
rubylibprefix=''
rubyw_install_name=''
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
setup=''
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sitearch=''
sitedir=''
sitehdrdir=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0'
target_alias=''
target_cpu='x86_64'
target_os='darwin12.3.0'
target_vendor='apple'
try_header=''
vendordir=''
vendorhdrdir=''
warnflags=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define CANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN 1

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: "See `config.log' for more details" <- do that, we can't guess what the actual error is.

Comment: Post the contents of `config.log`

Comment: @draxxxeus I've added the contents from the config.log file. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem.

In my case I tried to use the `RUBY_CFLAGS` variable [provided in this article](http://cbednarski.com/articles/installing-ruby/), which warns about it not being completely safe.

After trying and failing, I removed the corresponding line from `~/.bash_profile` but it failed again. The reason was that the variable was still defined in the current bash environment, so I had to `unset RUBY_CFLAGS` to be able to install a ruby version.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is occurred because gcc is not installed in your system.
All you have to do is to open your Xcode -> go to the preferences on top menu -> select Downloads tab -> in that window install command line tools

Now restart your terminal and try again

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the correct version of `gcc`.

It might be extra tricky on Mac thanks to Apple which provides some convoluted crap for gcc.

I removed all my gcc installations once by one using `brew remove gcc`, `brew remove gcc49` (used `brew search gcc` to find what's installed). Then ran rbenv install again and got a clear msg written for dummies like me.

```
(0)kashyap@vpn-client-163$ rbenv install 1.8.7-p352 --verbose

ERROR: This package must be compiled with GCC, but ruby-build couldn'tfind a suitable `gcc` executable on your system. Please install GCC
and try again.

DETAILS: Apple no longer includes the official GCC compiler with Xcode
as of version 4.2. Instead, the `gcc` executable is a symlink to
`llvm-gcc`, a modified version of GCC which outputs LLVM bytecode.

For most programs the `llvm-gcc` compiler works fine. However,
versions of Ruby older than 1.9.3-p125 are incompatible with
`llvm-gcc`. To build older versions of Ruby you must have the official
GCC compiler installed on your system.

TO FIX THE PROBLEM: Install Homebrew's apple-gcc42 package with this
command: brew tap homebrew/dupes ; brew install apple-gcc42

You will need to install the official GCC compiler to build older
versions of Ruby even if you have installed Apple's Command Line Tools
for Xcode package. The Command Line Tools for Xcode package only
includes `llvm-gcc`.

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.11.2 using ruby-build 20151216)


(1)kashyap@vpn-client-163$
```

Followed the instructions and voila..

```
(0)kashyap@vpn-client-163$ brew tap homebrew/dupes ;
==> Tapping homebrew/dupes
Cloning into '/usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-dupes'...
remote: Counting objects: 41, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (41/41), done.
remote: Total 41 (delta 0), reused 5 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (41/41), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Tapped 38 formulae (101 files, 412K)
(0)kashyap@vpn-client-163$
(0)kashyap@vpn-client-163$
(0)kashyap@vpn-client-163$
(0)kashyap@vpn-client-163$ brew install apple-gcc42
==> Installing apple-gcc42 from homebrew/dupes
==> Downloading http://r.research.att.com/tools/gcc-42-5666.3-darwin11.pkg
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> /bin/pax --insecure -rz -f usr.pkg/Payload -s ,./usr,/usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3,
==> Caveats
NOTE:
This formula provides components that were removed from XCode in the 4.2
release. There is no reason to install this formula if you are using a
version of XCode prior to 4.2.

This formula contains compilers built from Apple's GCC sources, build
5666.3, available from:

  http://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/gcc

All compilers have a `-4.2` suffix. A GFortran compiler is also included.
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3: 104 files, 75M, built in 16 seconds
(0)kashyap@vpn-client-163$
(0)kashyap@vpn-client-163$
(0)kashyap@vpn-client-163$
(0)kashyap@vpn-client-163$ rbenv install 1.8.7-p352 --verbose
/var/folders/kz/fmsnlrp510zc06ftjdltfhwm0000gn/T/ruby-build.20151231130202.59964 ~/repos/backlot
Downloading ruby-1.8.7-p352.tar.gz...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.8/ruby-1.8.7-p352.tar.gz
---------------- snip -------------
------------installed fine---------
(0)kashyap@vpn-client-163$
(0)kashyap@vpn-client-163$
(0)kashyap@vpn-client-163$
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using rbenv since a few years now and never ran into this problem before... but today I got the error on a Linux Mint setup.

The solution for me was simply to install some packages.

`sudo apt-get install build-essential` did the trick

Answer (score -1):

Try installing g++ and then `rbenv install ruby-1.9.3-p429`

Also, if you have no boundation, try `rvm`.

I am still not sure why `rbenv` is showing this error

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have g++ already installed. I have xCode 4.6.2. When I type g++ the command line returns: 
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2: no input files

Comment: Tried again, am still getting the same error as listed above. I am at a loss. I am wondering if I should just uninstall everything and start all over again?

Comment: Hey Draxxxeus, would you recommend completely uninstalling xcode and rbenv and then starting from scratch? I am not ready to give up on this yet. I like using rbenv. But, if there is no fix I may have to switch to rvm.

Comment: No, i wouldn't recommend that. I'll try to set `rbenv` on my box once and will let you know

Comment: No, I haven't tried to configure xcode in anyway... Also, I posted the entire config.log file in the original question. Thanks!

Comment: I just thought, uninstalling and reinstalling might help. That's all.